# how to extend the objects using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my following code,

```
points1 = [{x:'10'},{x:'20',fill:'red'}]
points2 = [{x:'30'},{x:'30'}]

   $.extend(true, points1, {}, points2);
```

it will be returned points1 as [{x:'30'},{x:'30',fill:'red'}] 
but what i need is ,if the fill is not available in points2 there should reflect..

my expected o/p is points1 = [{x:'30'},{x:'30'}]

how to achieve?

Comment: Your points variables are `Arrays`. `$.extend()` needs `Objects`

Comment: it's not clear enough what is you desired result. looks like you want to merge 2 arrays using some condition, but that condition is unclear

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. Just replace :

```
$.extend(true, points1, {}, points2);
```

with :

```
$.extend(false, points1, {}, points2);
```